# Open Internal Browser to Handle request

Tags: c#, http, oauth, windows-runtime

During the Oauth Process I retrieve a authorization URL like the following,

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&
response_type=code&
client_id=812741506391-h38jh0j4fv0ce1krdkiq0hfvt6n5amrf.apps.googleusercontent.com

This link just brings up a window with a text box that displays the authorization code. I was wondering is it possible in WinRT to either open up a internal browser that would allow me to interact with the link or use some sort of HTTP request to get the data?

Is it possible or will I have to just launch IE and make the user copy and paste?

Cheers.

Comment: You shouldn't have to open a instance of internet explorer nor make the user copy and paste the authorization code if your doing the request for the authorization code the correct way. Of course what you want certainly is possible its just a bad solution and goes against the entire point of OAuth.  Clearly based on this question you already know that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651493/sending-post-request-to-get-oauth-acess-token

Comment: @Ramhound sadly I am at the mercy of WinRT where there is little to no documentation on how to perform a full Oauth request. In this case I am just doing to implement the required functionality I am fully aware that it is not a standard way of doing things but sadly I don't have much of a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WebView control and navigate with it.